# How auto start background notification service without foreground notification on android 10?

Tags: android, mobile, service, xamarin.android, notifications

I'm using Xamarin Android like Android Java but i'm using C#.

The app automatically runs in the background and shows notification but cannot hide foreground notification.

How do other apps do this, for example Whatsapp?

My broadcast receiver for auto run background service:

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Android.Content.Intent.ActionBootCompleted, Android.Content.Intent.ActionDefault, Android.Content.Intent.ActionReboot, Android.Content.Intent.ActionShutdown, Android.Content.Intent.ActionPackageAdded, Android.Content.Intent.ActionPackageReplaced })]
public class BootDeviceReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        var action = intent.Action;

        if (Intent.ActionBootCompleted.Equals(action))
        {
            var notifyIntent = new Intent(context, typeof(NotificationService));

            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O)
            {
                context.StartForegroundService(notifyIntent);
            }
            else
            {
                context.StartService(notifyIntent);
            }

            Toast.MakeText(context, "Receiver start service", ToastLength.Long).Show();
        }
    }
}
```

My notification service:

```
   [Service]
    public class NotificationService : Service
    {
        const string CHANNEL_ID = "1";
        const string CHANNEL_NAME = "1";
        public static int _notifyId = int.MinValue;
        public static Context _ctx;
        public static Service _service;

        public int MyProperty { get; set; }

        public enum NotifyType
        {
            ERROR = 0,
            CLEAR = 1,
            NEW = 2
        };

        public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
        {
            if (intent == null)
            {
                return StartCommandResult.StickyCompatibility;
            }

            _ctx = this;
            _service = this;

            var notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);

            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O)
            {
                NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationImportance.Default);

                notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
            }

            OtoEksper.MyExper.Base.NotificationService.Notify("Foreground Notification", "Cannot be closed.", NotifyType.CLEAR);

            OtoEksper.MyExper.Base.NotificationService.Notify("Normal Notification", "Can be closed", NotifyType.CLEAR, false, notificationManager, "google.com");

            return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
        }

        public static void Notify(string title, string content, NotifyType type, bool foreground = true, NotificationManager notificationManager = null, string url = "")
        {
            var dw = type == NotifyType.CLEAR ? Resource.Drawable.notify :
                (type == NotifyType.NEW ? Resource.Drawable.notify : Resource.Drawable.notify);

            var readIntent = new Intent(_ctx, typeof(ReadNotificationActivity));

            if (!foreground)
            {
                if (_notifyId == int.MaxValue)
                {
                    _notifyId = int.MinValue;
                }

                readIntent.PutExtra(Constants.Constants.INTENT_PARAM_NOTIFY_ID, _notifyId);
            }

            var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(_ctx, 0, readIntent, PendingIntentFlags.CancelCurrent);

            var largeICon = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(_ctx.Resources, dw);

            var soundUri = RingtoneManager.GetDefaultUri(RingtoneType.Alarm);

            var notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(_ctx, CHANNEL_ID)
                .SetContentTitle(title)
                .SetContentText(content)
                .SetSmallIcon(dw)
                .SetLargeIcon(largeICon)
                .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .SetVisibility(1)
                .SetSound(soundUri)
                .Build();

            if (foreground)
            {
                var notification2 = new NotificationCompat.Builder(_ctx, CHANNEL_ID)
                .SetContentTitle(title)
                .SetContentText(content)
                .SetSmallIcon(dw)
                .SetLargeIcon(largeICon)
                .Build();

                _service.StartForeground(1, notification2);
            }
            else
            {
                notificationManager.Notify(_notifyId++, notification);
            }
        }
    }
```

MainActivity:

```
   [Activity(Label = "Main", Theme = "@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        protected async override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

            var notifyIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(NotificationService));

            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O)
            {
                StartForegroundService(notifyIntent);
            }
            else
            {
                StartService(notifyIntent);
            }
        }

        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }

        protected override void OnRestart()
        {
            Finish();
            StartActivity(Intent);

            base.OnRestart();
        }
    }
```

Android manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionName="1.11" package="com.example.wwww" android:installLocation="preferExternal" android:versionCode="11">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="29" />
    <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" android:allowBackup="true" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:label="@string/app_name" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:supportsRtl="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
    
  </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
</manifest>
```

Comment: afaik thats new policy, every background task must have visual representation on screen (thus `Notification`)